# Writing code with multiple Class Methods and String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, methods

So what I am trying to do is create a code that lists music artists names using user input.
It has to have multiple classes so I will have a main class, and a class for each decade of music.

```
Music.java

six.java

seven.java

eight.java
```

In these classes I need to create string arrays that contain artist names, and be able to generate the entire list once prompted.

To give a better idea of how the code will run it would go something like:

Choose a decade of music:

- 70's

Choose a genre of music:

- Rock

Choices are: Rolling Stones, Talking Heads, etc.

That's all I need it to do but I'm getting stuck on what to put in the main class "music.java" to get it to read the other classes and furthermore how to write the decade classes.

I understand I don't have much to offer you guys here but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "...so I will have a main class, and a class for each decade of music." 0_0 **Why?** Why not make decade (or better yet, year of release) an **attribute** of a song?

Comment: why can't you have a class named 'Decade` and then assign the value 60, 70, etc. upon constructing instead of having a different class for each decade ?

Comment: Well, the way I've set it up is about the only way I could even begin to figure it out. I'm new to all of this and honestly longer makes it easier for me follow, I don't know many shortcuts or even how to write basic code very well.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this project?  You may want to start out with a basic Java tutorial if you are just trying to learn Java.

Comment: @Clueless - Scrap your entire design.

Comment: Or you could have a list of decades as an attribute on artist. Or a list of songs assigned to an artist and the decade as an attribute on the song. Requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I would only have a class named `Band` and a container class for all bands named `BandRegister`.  The Band would hold a `Set` of values representing the decade, which are added using `associateWithDecate(int decade)` method:

Class BandRegister:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Band>) decadeMap = new HahMap...

public addBand(band);
{
//define logic for adding the decade and band to decadeMap
}
```

Class Band:

```
Set<Integer> decades = ...

public associateWithDecate(int decade)
{
//add decade to decades if not already included
}
```

In Main:

```
    BandRegister breg = new BandRegister();

        Band stones = new Band("Rolling Stones");
        stones.associateWithDecate(60);
        stones.associateWithDecate(70);
        stones.associateWithDecate(70);
        stones.associateWithDecate(90);
        stones.associateWithDecate(0);
        stones.associateWithDecate(10);
breg.addband(stones);
```

That way, you can get a listing of decades for each band and also in the register you can get a listing of bands for each decade

Comment: I probably would not pass in a registration object into the band object.  That doesn't make sense.  You should be passing the band into the BandRegistration object.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, you need a class in this rough form:

```
 public class Artist
 {
    public int decade

    public string genre
 }
```

Then some code to use it:

... code to retrieve some kind of collection (e.g. an array or list), of artists as Artist objects (you'll need to do this by retrieving the artist data from a database)

... code to iterate through the collection to do what you want with it: